# Usar datos de una pagina web en mi aplicación

Tags: java, android-studio, web, http

estoy intentando una aplicación y para que funcione correctamente necesito saber el precio de la gasolina en España en tiempo real. No sé de dónde sacar esa información ni cómo meterla en mi aplicación. Estoy intentando crearla desde Android Studio y en Java. 
Muchas gracias.

Comment: intenta buscar una api-rest que te de esos valores, ya sea por json o xml,
y una vez tengas esos valor tendra que usar librerias para interpretarlos retrofit o ksoap2, investiga con eso.

Comment: https://sede.minetur.gob.es/es-ES/datosabiertos/catalogo/precios-carburantes
aqui tienes algo

Answer (score -4):

lo más normal es hacerlo a través de una API-Rest.

Sí quieres la información del precio de la gasolina en España, el ministerio proporciona APIs gratuitas para sacar información: [Aquí puedes ver algunas de las apis relacionadas con el gasoil](https://sede.minetur.gob.es/es-ES/datosabiertos/catalogo/precios-carburantes), [Aquí la del precio de la gasolina en las gasolineras](https://sedeaplicaciones.minetur.gob.es/ServiciosRESTCarburantes/PreciosCarburantes/EstacionesTerrestres/)

Tendrás que hacer la llamada a esa API cada vez que quieras que se actualice el precio, el formato parece ser XML.

Un saludo!

Comment: se te agradece el apoyo pero por favor evita responder a preguntas mal planteadas como esta, que no muestra ni un intento o avance por cuenta del OP